# Black box model and white box model fusion

Tags: regression, transformers

I have two models:
Black Box: Fedformer https://github.com/Zero-coder/FEDformer
White Box: A linear function

I want to predict home load, I use Black box predic time-series got a pth file. Then I use White box to calculate load base on linear math function either. I want to add weight for these two models to get a better prediction. Hope can get some hint about how to fusion these two models results?